# Dictionaries in DLLs

Tags: c#, dictionary

i've got this code:

```
public class Extension
{
    Dictionary<string, string> exts = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    public static void Add(string extcode, string desc)
    {
        exts.Add(extcode, desc);
    }
    public static void Del(string extcode)
    {
        if(exts.ContainsKey(extcode))
        {
            exts.Remove(extcode);
        }
    }
    public static bool Exists(string extcode)
    {
        if(exts.ContainsKey(extcode))
        {
            return true;
        }
        if(!exts.ContainsKey(extcode))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And the problem is when I try to use the exts Dictionary inside the classes Add, Del and Exists, it says:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property "Filext.Extension.Ext"

I want to use the Dictionary methods in every function without creating a new dictionary or cloning it.
The idea is when i use `Extension.Add("aaa","description")`, `Remove("aaa")` or `Exists("aaa")`, add or remove it from the dictionary by the key.

Comment: Where is `Ext` defined?

Comment: Your Exists method is ridiculously complex. It should just `return exts.ContainsKey(extcode)`. You're looking up the key *twice* for no reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your methods are `static`, hence your `Dictionary` declaration should be `static` as well. You can't use a class *instance member* inside a static method.

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> exts = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that methods of this class are defined `static`. You have two solutions: the better one is to define thos methods static by removing the `static` keyword before method definitions. The worst solution is to define that `ext` dictionary `static`.